# how to sort List<Entity>?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, wcf-ria-services

Suppose I have a List:

```
MyList = new List<MyEntity>();
```

then I try to add item to the list. Each item loaded by WCF RIA Service with async call.
I want MyList always sorted by a property of MyEntity,  say it's ID, after any new item added,

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: What does `MyEntity` look like? What is its definition?

Comment: Not try yet. Because I can't control the order of async complete, so the order is random. every time run the app, user get different order in UI.

Comment: MyEntity is Entity from Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SortedSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070) to keep it sorted

```
       SortedSet<int> x = new SortedSet<int>();

        x.Add(5);
        x.Add(1);
        x.Add(23);
        x.Add(51);

        foreach (var i in x)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
```

will print

```
1
5
23
51
```

Comment: change the type would also need to change data binding in UI. Any more simple solution?

Comment: @KentZhou In that case, how big is your list going to be? Are you willing to you inefficient solution?

Comment: Also SortedSet is not available for Sliverlight.

Comment: @KentZhou If you care about Silverlight or some other limited version of .Net, you should always state that in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either

```
Mylist.Sort();
```

or

```
MyList.OrderBy();
```

Probably the latter would be better for you to specify a property

```
MyList.OrderBy(x => x.ID);
```

As others have said, this is not efficient and a SortedSet would be the better choice, but if changing the type is not an option, then this is one possibility.

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` is not a sorted container, and keeping it ordered by calling sort after insert is not the best way to do it. Use a container which is sorted by definition instead, such as a tree based collection or `SortedSet`

Answer (score 1):

If it is very important that you use a List<Entity> collection then you can use BinarySearch to locate position.

```
int index = MyList.BinarySearch(newMyEntity, yourComparer);
if (index < 0)
    MyList.Insert(~index, newMyEntity);
else
    // An identical item has been found.
```

yourComparer is an instance of a IComparer<MyEntity>.  You can avoid it if MyEntity implements the IComparable<MyEntity> interface.

Please note that the Insert-statement is rather inefficient, expect performance like O(n/2).

Hope this will help you in your quest.